# New garbage disposal drain is a bit higher than stubout on wall

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal, p-trap

So I'm in a basement that is below the drain-level of the house, and there's a small kitchenette, bathroom, and thus a sump pump.

I decided to in garbage disposal unit (there wasn't one before) in order to help prevent any large bits of food waste that fall into the sink from clogging the drain or pump.

I was able to install the disposal no problem, however, now the drain is higher than the disposal!

[image: drains]

Okay, so I think the proper fix for this is to lower the stubout by cutting the vertical part down, so I cut thru the cabinet and drywall, and see this:

[image: stubout]

But behold! It's a weird sanitary tree... WTH.!? is that even up to code? I can't really do anything with that other than cut it out of the horizontal main drain line, right? I really wanted to avoid cutting into the main line drain, but is that my only choice here? What else can I do to lower the stubout?

Comment: That's not a sanitary tee, it's a combo wye. Afaik it's *required* by code for a vertical to horizontal connection like that.

Comment: How far do you need to lower the drain stub-out?  If you aren't worried about the project getting a little bigger, you could cut out the existing **Combo Wye with 45-degree Elbow** (the name of the current fitting) and replace it with a new one, turned outward toward the wall 45-degrees; then put a 45 on it to meet the P-trap.  That will probably allow you to lower the drain several inches.  You will have a venting problem, but I think you already have one.  Maybe add an AAV to help with it.  Supply house link to fitting: https://www.supplyhouse.com/PVC-DWV-Fittings-14951000

Comment: @JeffWheeler need it 4 inches lower at least I think... I'm not sure I quite follow how replacing it with the exact same combo wye+45elbow will lower it

Comment: Right now the fitting tees up vertically 90-degrees from the branch drain.  Imagine you twist the fitting toward yourself 45-degrees so it's not pointing straight up anymore; it's now coming out of the wall a bit lower.  Then use a **45-degree Street Elbow** to get it level so you can connect the P-trap.  (45 deg street elbow link https://www.supplyhouse.com/PVC-DWV-Fittings-14951000)  These two fitting changes should give you a few inches.  Not sure it's enough but it might be.

Comment: Regarding the above, if you buy the fittings and just hold them together with the Wye level with the current branch drain, you will be able to predict exactly where the modified stub-out would be, vertically, to see if it's low enough.  You can mock it up before cutting the existing drain to see if it's going to work.  Only costs you a few dollars in fittings to find out.

Comment: @JeffWheeler Thanks... I think I understand... so basically do this: https://i.imgur.com/7e29367.png

Comment: Yes.  You might have already guessed what you can do if you need the drain a little lower, too; just rotate the fitting further down; as long as it has at least 1/4"-per-foot slope it will drain correctly.  Just don't make it completely flat or it'll clog up over time.

Comment: @JeffWheeler I think it came out better than I was expecting, added an in-line vent, since I don't think the basement had a roof vent connection anywhere. Had some trouble coupling the main drain line back together though. https://i.imgur.com/qiQokV0.png BTW: Copy your comments into an answer (*wink wink*)